# Infinite loop of redirects - how do I fix the .htaccess files?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

I've got .htaccess files looping on me.

The site is currently an old Joomla site which I'm trying to replace with a Word Press site.
I've installed WP in a subdirectory called /new. Once I'm happy with the WP site I'll delete the Joomla one.

At the moment if I try to access anything at www.mysite.com.au/new it wont load and I get an error message that I have too many redirects.

In the top level I have this

```
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 423 2005-10-09 18:23:50Z stingrey $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##

#
#  mod_rewrite in use
#

RewriteEngine On

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL 
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update YourJoomlaDirectory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /YourJoomlaDirectory

#
#  Rules
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

RedirectMatch permanent ^/ContactUs.htm$ http://www.sitename.com.au/content/view/14/30/

RedirectMatch permanent ^/Contents.htm$ http://www.sitename.com.au/content/view/21/57

RedirectMatch permanent ^/new/$ http://www.sitename.com.au/new/index.php/
```

And in the /new directory I have this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I just cant see it... any suggestions ?

cheers

Comment: Try commenting out: `RedirectMatch permanent ^/new/$...` line.

Comment: Fantastic - that fixes it.  (I'd put that line when I was trying to install WP, and that did the trick then, but was clearly not good for later).    Thanks so much! cheers

Comment: OK posted that as answer. You can accept it since it helped you solve your problem. For further problems you can create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out:

```
 RedirectMatch permanent ^/new/$...
```

line to avoid infinite lopping.